# Python list/set comprehension with characters

Tags: python

I was trying to get a set of all characters from a list of strings using two level comprehension:

```
words = ['foo','bar']
s = {c for c in w for w in l}
```

But got the following error:

```
NameError: name 'w' is not defined
```

I wonder if it is because w is not a list object. If so is there any other way we can quickly get character set from a list of strings?

Comment: you never used the `words` variable. im a bit confused if you expect this to run.

Comment: My bad. I was copying some codes. The name of list should be l instead of ‘words’

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [comprehension in python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) ist evaluated from the left to right. That means, your outer loop has to come first. Therefore you need to swap the loops:

```
 words = ['foo','bar']
 s = {c for w in words for c in w}
```

Output:

```
 {'a', 'b', 'r', 'f', 'o'}
```

Comment: I think it misses one character, the second "o"?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is right, if you want all characters, including duplicates you need a list instead of a set, simply replace the curly brackets `{}` with square brackets `[]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I thought he wanted to output all characters.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
words = ['foo','bar']
s = [[c1 for c1 in word] for word in words]
print(s)
```

Output :

```
[['f', 'o', 'o'], ['b', 'a', 'r']]
```